# How to filter out/ommit specific pattern in linux logs

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

I'm looking through massive log files on linux server. Is there any command to filter out (not to show) specific pattern?
For example if my log messages begin with A-1111, B-1111, C-1111 etc. Could I somehow filter so that logs with pattern A-XXXX wouldn't be shown, but all other patterns still would be present?

I' not really advanced with linux commands, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the reasons why `grep` has been invented. However, from your description I can't find out how the pattern looks like:

```
[A-C]-1111                 : letters from A to C, followed by 1111
[A-C]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] : letters from A to C, followed by four digits
[A-Z]...                   : letters from A to Z, ...
...
```

Your first reaction: *"This is not what I want: grep filters those expressions and shows them, and I want the opposite, I want not to show them!"*

This can be solved by the `-v` flag in `grep`:

I have created a file with following content:

```
A-1111
B-1111
C-1111
A-2222
Whatever
```

This is the result of `grep -v "[A-C]-1111" logfile.log`:

```
A-2222
Whatever
```

Comment: Great! The pattern is irrelevant, the `-v` flag would be enough for me, thank you!